# RoadMap для парсера и автоматизации в аккаунте

Tags: python, парсер, автоматизация

помогите составить роадМап для выполнения условий:
1)на одном сайте выполняется необходимое условие
2)после выполняется вход на букмекерской конторе
3) находится этот матч
4) и делается ставка в процентном соотношении
~ примерно такая логика
подскажите какие материалы нужно изучить, желательно стабильные, а так же что бы максимально скрыть механические действия при входе в аккаунт